# SQL query to compare 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 3 columns id, visit date and appointment date.
I want to write a sql query to find the following
For each id, how many entries are there where visit date matches with appointment date. Please note that the comparison has to happen across multiple rows for each id. 
Example:

```
id  Visit-date  Appointment-date
1     20-1-2016   20-2-2016
1     20-2-2016   30-3-2016
1     04-04-2016  05-05-2016
```

and so on

Thanks a lot for the help.
Prasad

Comment: What do you mean with "accross multiple rows"?

Comment: TO be more clear, for each appointment-date within an id, the query has to report if there are any matching vist-dates or not. In the above example, the matching combination is Appointment date : 20-2-2016 and visit date : 20-2-2016 ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join with aggregation to get the desired results:

```
select a.id,
    count(b.appointment_date) as count
from your_table a
left join your_table b on a.id = b.id
    and a.visit_date = b.appointment_date
group by a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count records grouping by id.

```
select    id, count(*) num_records
from      your_table
where     visit_date = appointment_date
group  by id
```